# realloc memory Access violation reading location

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks, realloc

Probably my brain is not working properly now... I wonder why I receive mentioned error in my code:

```
int ** zm;
zm = (int**)calloc(1, sizeof(int*));
*zm = (int*)calloc(1, sizeof(int));
*zm[0] = 5;
*zm = (int*)realloc(*zm, 2*sizeof(int));
*zm[1] = 10; // Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Could someone explain what happend in that code?

Comment: “I wonder why I receive mentioned error in my code” because you use `calloc` and `realloc` instead of `std::vector`. See http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks.

Comment: Did you think `*zm[0]` is `(*zm)[0]`? It is `*(zm[0])` in fact.

Comment: @rightfold While using `std::vector` is probably the preferred way of dealing with vectors/arrays in modern C++, the errors in the above code are not a direct result of not using `std::vector`. `calloc`/`realloc` are still useful in some circumstances and do not magically cause errors to spring into existence. Granted, they can be tricky to use properly, though...

Comment: @rightfold , twalberg
Ok, my fault I choose category c++ but I'm using Asni-C in fact. I can't use vector. But your comment haven't solve this certain problem at all.

Comment: @rightfold Your answer is like Q: "I have a problem with my windows, how can I solve it?" A: "Use linux". Problem is regarding realloc and your answer "use vector".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrong indexing, try `(*zm)[1]` instead. And check for errors from library calls.

Comment: Yup, you are right. No I came to conclusion that I have first indexed and then take value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try *(zm+1) to assign value of second element
*(zm+1)=10;